# Policy Based Design - Conditional use of Base class (functions)

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, policy

In the hello world example of policy based design from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design) we have this very nice way of defining the implementation (policy-) specific member functions via `using` directives:

```c++
template <typename OutputPolicy, typename LanguagePolicy>
class HelloWorld : private OutputPolicy, private LanguagePolicy {
public:
// Behavior method.
void Run() const {
   // Two policy methods.
   Print(Message());
}

private:
using LanguagePolicy::Message;
using OutputPolicy::Print;
};
```

Now assume that you want to allow a user to forget implementing the `Message` method in the language policy - there can be many others the user did implement. Hence, you define a fallback class

```c++
class DefaultLanguagePolicy {
protected:
  std::string Message() const { return ""; }
  // and fallbacks for other methods a user may not have implemented
}
```

But how do you enable this default if `Message` is not implemented in the `HelloWorld` Class and discard it otherwise?

```c++
template <typename OutputPolicy, typename LanguagePolicy, typename DefaultLanguagePolicy>
class HelloWorld : private OutputPolicy, private LanguagePolicy, private DefaultLanguagePolicy {
public:
// Behavior method.
 void Run() const {
   // Two policy methods.
   Print(Message());
 }

 private:
 // what do I need to write to get this kind of behaviour:
 if (LanguagePolicy has Message implemented) {
    using LanguagePolicy::Message;
 } else {
    using DefaultLanguagePolicy::Message;
 }
   using OutputPolicy::Print;
 };
```

Thanks for any suggestions that ideally allow to keep this nice `using` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can be set design decision in the project, that every policy derives from default-policy - like:

```
class SomeLangaugePolicy : public DefaultLanguagePolicy { ... };
```

Then there is nothing to be changed in class `HelloWorld` - I mean the first version of this class.

---

Otherwise - use tools from `<type_traits>`:

Detecting if the given class has Message function is possible by using [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t)

```
template <typename T, typename = std::void_t<>> 
struct has_message : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> 
struct has_message<T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::Message)>> : std::true_type {};
```

With this `has_message` trait, with [`std::conditional_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) is possible to select type depending on `Message` presence:

```
template <typename LanguagePolicy, typename DefaultLanguagePolicy>
using LanguageBase = std::conditional_t<has_message<LanguagePolicy>::value,
                                        LanguagePolicy, 
                                        DefaultLanguagePolicy>;
```

And needed modifications in your class:

```
template <typename OutputPolicy, typename LanguagePolicy, typename DefaultLanguagePolicy>
class HelloWorld : 
         private OutputPolicy, 
         private LanguageBase<LanguagePolicy, DefaultLanguagePolicy> {
public:
    // Behavior method.
    void Run() const {
        // Two policy methods.
        Print(Message());
    }

private:
    using LanguageBase<LanguagePolicy, DefaultLanguagePolicy>::Message;
    using OutputPolicy::Print;
};
```

Working [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yiNEIZIAPIgnsAIm)

Now it is easy to do the same with OutputPolicy and all other policies.

You might define macro to define policy detectors:

```
#define DEFINE_HAS_FUNCTION_TRAIT(function) \
template <typename T, typename = std::void_t<>> \ 
struct has_##function : std::false_type {}; \
template <typename T> \
struct has_##function<T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::function)>> : std::true_type {}
```

Then:

```
DEFINE_HAS_FUNCTION_TRAIT(Message); // define has_Message
DEFINE_HAS_FUNCTION_TRAIT(Print); // define has_Print
```

To handle case when there are more functions in the given Policy than just one - use this approach:

```
template <typename OutputPolicy, typename LanguagePolicy, typename DefaultLanguagePolicy>
class HelloWorld : 
         private OutputPolicy, 
         private LanguagePolicy, private DefaultLanguagePolicy {
public:
    // Behavior method.
    void Run() const {
        // Two policy methods.
        Print(Message());
    }

private:
    using std::conditional_t<has_Message<LanguagePolicy>::value,
                             LanguagePolicy, 
                             DefaultLanguagePolicy>::Message;
    using OutputPolicy::Print;
};
```

Comment: @PiortrNycz Thanks a lot. That works. It does, however, require to define a different trait for the presence/absence of every method in `LanguagePolicy`.  Could there be a simpler way? Its safe to assume that `LanguagePolicy` implements a subset of `DefaultLanguagePolicy` - so for every method that is missing in `LanguagePolicy`, there is definitely one in `DefaultLanguagePolicy`.

Comment: In fact, now that I think of it more, I see another problem:  you define `LanguageBase` dependent on `has_ message` - but isn't that impractical if there are other functions in in `LanguagePolicy` that may be absent and need defaults, right?

Comment: So with defining traits `has_function` for every function that `LanguagePolicy` may implement, one can simply omit the definition of `LanguageBase` and put the `std::conditional` directly into the `private:` parts of `HelloWorld` - that is exactly the kind of if clause I was looking for.

Comment: You might define macro to detect any such kind of "function". And - of course you might use conditional_t directly, However IMHO - it is easier to have such helper typedefs like LaungageBase

Comment: I provided solution for cases when there is more function to detect in one policy class.

Comment: Brilliant! That is so nice - esp. with the macro. Thanks so much! As for the suggestion to derive LanguagePolicy from LanguagePolicyDefault that is not an option for me, that is also, good but not an option for me. In my case, the default needs some things (some dimensional settings) that are only available from the non-default policy.

Comment: Another aspect of the macro solution is that this makes it convenient to define the has_function inside a class which is necessary to check for the availability of private member functions. So again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You may set the template parameter a default value, and the class will use your DefaultLanguagePolicy, if the user didn't provide the second template parameter. Does this meets your purpose?

The `DefaultLanguagePolicy` has to be defined before the class `HelloWorld`.

```
 class DefaultLanguagePolicy {
   protected:
   std::string Message() const { return "Please add a language policy\n"; }
 };

template <typename OutputPolicy, typename LanguagePolicy = DefaultLanguagePolicy>
 class HelloWorld : private OutputPolicy, private LanguagePolicy {
 public:
  void Run() const {
       Print(Message());
     }
```

A test run will print `Please add a language policy.` in case that the language policy is not provided.

```
int main() {
    typedef HelloWorld<OutputPolicyWriteToCout> myDeafult;
    myDeafult forgetLanguage;
    forgetLanguage.Run();

    HelloWorld<OutputPolicyWriteToCout, LanguagePolicyGerman> InGerman;
    InGerman.Run();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. This is possible but as far as I understand would overwrite __all__ methods in the the LanguagePolicy class with defaults, would it not?. I'm looking for a way to only call the default when a __specific method__ is not implemented.

Comment: No. If the second parameter is provided. It will be used. Please test it.

Comment: I fear the example is too simple. Assume that `LanguagePolicy` has more than one method to it. All but `Message` are implemented and thus only `Message` needs to be filled in with a default. Putting a default template parameter as you suggest would overwrite all specific implementations of `LanguagePolicy`with defaults, wouldn't it? I'll edit the question to make this clearer.

Comment: @JReichardt No. It won't overwrite the other language output. Last example, I use the object name to be HellowWorld. This casue trouble in mixed with the class name. I changed the variable name in the eidted version. It works now.

Comment: I believe we're misunderstanding us. According to my understanding, your solution provides a default for the entire implementation of `LanguagePolicy`. It's all or nothing. What I'm looking for instead is a way to only provide defaults to the specific methods of `LanguagePolicy` that may be absent. The class itself is implemented - just not with all the functions `HelloWorld` would like to call on it. Does that clarify things? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I am not misunderstood, and a default is not overwrite other policies. Just run my new main(). And, you have to add other polycies, of course., which I didn’t included in my post.